# XmlDocument.Load() triggering a 407 proxy error

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

When running this piece of code

```
string html_source = browser.PageSource;
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("C:/test.xml");
w.Write(html_source);
w.Close();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:/test.xml");
```

I am getting this error on the Load() method:

```
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

My goal is to parse a few elements using XPath, however I cannot even load the HTML document in a XmlDocument to parse it without triggering the proxy authentication failure ?

I am not sure why this happens and how I could avoid the proxy error.

Comment: Does your XML document reference a DTD?

Comment: "HTML document in a XmlDocument" - going to fail... Any particular reason not to use HtmlAgilityPack? (HTML is *not* XML)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: yes it is, I found that using DtdProcessing.Ignore allows me to get past this error. Feel free to reply if you want to.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: can I use XPath to select nodes using HtmlAgilityPack ?

Comment: Yes, you can use XPath to select nodes using HtmlAgilityPack. Here are some related answers - http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20HtmlAgilityPack